# Error installing perl module (cpan and manually)

Tags: perl, module

I'm trying to install the SQL::Translator module. Everything runs fine until it gets to this test:

```
DBD::SQLite::db do failed: not an error at t/sqlite-rename-field.t line 62.
#   Failed test '-- Convert schema '' to '':;'
#   at t/sqlite-rename-field.t line 62.
# died: Died at t/sqlite-rename-field.t line 62.
# Looks like you failed 1 test of 16.
Failed 1/72 test programs. 1/1901 subtests failed.
make: *** [test_dynamic] Error 1
```

Any help is much appreciated, I was not able to find any similar questions. Thanks.

cpan link: http://search.cpan.org/~ilmari/SQL-Translator-0.11021/lib/SQL/Translator.pm

Comment: Suggest [contacting the module author](http://search.cpan.org/~ilmari/SQL-Translator-0.11021/lib/SQL/Translator.pm#GETTING_HELP/SUPPORT).

Comment: I'm seeing all tests pass. Are you using up-to-date versions of Perl, `DBI`, and `DBD::SQLite`?

Comment: Hi rutter, the server I'm working with is running Perl 5.10.1, DBI 1.609, and DBD::SQLite 1.27. I am a bit wary about updating to the latest versions since I'm not sure if it would mess with anything else on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be because of missing dependencies and/or mismatch in version of other perl modules. Try using [CPANM](http://search.cpan.org/~miyagawa/App-cpanminus-1.7034/bin/cpanm) to install your desired package. It will take care of dependencies for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to install `libsql-translator-perl` library if you are on debian based systems. I am sure there will be a compatible library on red hat based systems too.

Also if you want to install from cpan then use `CPANM` to install the module.

Personally i prefer to use distro libraries in place of installing modules.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone stumbles across this question, my solution was:

- install perlbrew
- install latest version of perl via perlbrew
- download required libraries
- install module

It was much easier than dealing with the older system